# Split preg_match with many separator in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, split, separator

i have string data like these:

```
$productList="
Saluran Dua(Bothway)-(TAN007);
Speedy Password-(INET PASS);
Memo-(T-Memo);
7-pib r-10/10-(AM);
FBI (R/N/M)-(Rr);
";
```

how can i split them, so the result is:

```
Array1(
[0]=>Saluran Dua(Bothway)
[1]=>Speedy Password
[2]=>Memo
[3]=>7-pib r-10/10
[4]=>FBI (R/N/M)
);

Array2(
[0]=>TAN007
[1]=>INET PASS
[2]=>T-Memo
[3]=>AM
[4]=>Rr
);
```

i tried `preg_match_all`, this is for array1:

```
$separator = '/\-\(([A-z ]*)\)/';
preg_match_all($separator, $productList, $match);
$value=$match[1];
```

and this is for array2:

```
$separator2 = '/\;([A-z ]*)\-/';
preg_match_all($separator2, $productList, $desc);
$desc=$desc[1];
```

the result is showed, some of them right and some else disappear.. i believe there's wrong in preg_match_all. i hope you can give me solution..

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

```
preg_match_all('(^(.*)-\((.*)\);$)m',$productList,$matches);
list(,$value,$desc) = $matches;
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/uQNeOD)

Comment: thanks before, but when i run it, it gives me `500 Internal Server Error` . but if i remove it, it run well.. @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: That's bizarre. Do you have any error logs you can look at to find the cause of the error? What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: i use PHP Version 5.4.16 .. no, there's no description of the error.. just show `500 Internal Server Error` then `connection close` . if i remove it, there's no error @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: the array result is null..sorry @NiettheDarkAbsol , but could you separate it one by one.. preg_match_all for $value first..then for $desc . maybe that cause the error in my code..